# Class-level validator for REST api not even executing the validator

Tags: java, rest, validation, jersey

I have a REST api like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/dopost")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("text/plain")
public String doPostExample(@Valid @BeanParam final DemoBean demo) {

         return "done";
}
```

The input is store into this bean:

```
@Address
public class DemoBean {

    private String address;

    private String city;

    // Other member variables

    // getters and setters
}
```

As I want to validate a group of fields together (related to location), I created a class-level validator.

Here's the annotation I created:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = AddressValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Address {

    String message() default "{com.mycompany.constraints.checkcase}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

And here there is the validator:

```
public class AddressValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Address, Address> {

   public void initialize(Address constraintAnnotation) {
        // initialize the zipcode/city/country correlation service
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isValid(Address address, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return true; // I put a breakpoint here, but it doesn't stop here and I have the stack trace below
    }
}
```

However something must be terribly wrong because it doesn't work. I get this stack trace in the log:

```
03-Mar-2017 16:31:25.282 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationExceptionMapper.toResponse Unexpected Bean Validation problem.
 javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: com.admin.input.DemoBean.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:547)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:723)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:992)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.DefaultConfiguredValidator.onValidate(DefaultConfiguredValidator.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ValidationInterceptorExecutor.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.DefaultConfiguredValidator.validateResourceAndInputParams(DefaultConfiguredValidator.java:146)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Just went through the same struggle... the error message really sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `AddressValidator` class. Both Generic arguments `ConstraintValidator<Address, Address>` refers to your `Adress` annotation class. This is not correct. First argument should be your annotation and second argument should be your DemoBean as shown below.

```
public class AddressValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Address, DemoBean> {

    public void initialize(Address constraintAnnotation) {
      // initialize the zipcode/city/country correlation service
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(DemoBean addressBean, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return true; 
    }
}
```